# How to change size of CKEditor toolbar?

Tags: height, ckeditor, toolbar

Is it possible to do CKEditor's toolbar smaller? Height and weight attributes only changes editor's size but I want to change toolbar's size.

Answer (score 3):

You can always locate the div that includes the toolbar and set the `zoom`.

For example on my cfkEditor tests I found that the `cke_top` is used for the tool bar, and I just add this css:

```
.cke_top
{
    zoom:0.8;
}
```

I found a random example of this editor here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgifford/C7N7r/

and here I apply the above style: http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/54/

One bug that have is that the drop down lists are not opened on correct position.

To solve that I locate also the opened panels and add zoom there too, but did not make it work so good up to now.

```
.cke_combopanel
{
    zoom:0.85;
}

.cke_panel_frame
{
    zoom:0.8;
}
```

and the final: http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/225/

So you can use that trick on a smaller version of the tool bar with out the drop down lists.

Comment: Plus for mentioning zoom. Very underrated feature.

Answer (score 1):

To get the width right in IE9 without changing any other styles I applied the zoom to .cke_toolbar instead

```
.cke_toolbar {
    zoom: 0.8;
}
```

For consistency you can put it in both editor.css and editor_ie.css though all you really need it in is the IE one, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/74/

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make toolbar smaller for my app too. Here's what I've done.

```
.cke_top { padding: 6px 0 0 6px !important; }
.cke_voice_label,
.cke_button_label,
.cke_combo_label { display: none !important; }
a.cke_button { padding: 3px 4px !important; }
.cke_combo_text { padding-left: 6px !important; line-height: 24px !important; }
.cke_combo_open { height: 18px !important; line-height: 16px !important;}
.cke_combo_arrow { margin: 10px 0 0 !important; }
```

The version of CKEditor is 4.5.6.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! But some problems with the hover.

Comment: Fix: a.cke_button_off:hover,a.cke_button_off:focus,a.cke_button_off:active{border:0px!important; }

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There's no official support for such thing. Still, you can modify [editor's skin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/skins/moono/toolbar.css) on your own and eventually [re-build the editor](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets).

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit ambiguous as to the desired result; I just had a need to create a more compact toolbar for an editor with limited functionality that is not envisaged to be used that often anyway. The default styles add a lot of padding in that is not really necessary in this case; the following styles will eliminate it while still looking reasonable.

Hopefully this answer is useful for people who get here with similar requirements!

```
.rte.compact + .cke .cke_top {
    padding: 1px;
}

.rte.compact + .cke .cke_toolgroup {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.rte.compact + .cke .cke_toolbar_separator {
    height: 12px;
}

.rte.compact + .cke .cke_toolgroup a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Used for CKE-ing a field set up as:

```
<textarea class="rte compact"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **CKEditor 5**, I used this trick with `CSS`

```
.ck.ck-toolbar.ck-toolbar_grouping {
  zoom: 0.7 !important;
}
```

Yo can change the `zoom` as you need.

**UPDATE**: I found an issue with the `tooltip_text` because it was being showing so far from the options. So I had to do some tricks:

1. Remove the `zoom` option
2. Set a `font-size` for the icons to decrease their size (replacing the zoom option). In my case `9px`.
3. play with the **toolbar** to hide it if there is space available to show icons. NOTE: I had to change the `min-width` and `min-height`. Modify it as you need it.

   .ck.ck-toolbar.ck-toolbar_grouping {
   /* zoom: 0.8 !important; */
   }

   .ck.ck-icon {
   font-size: 9px !important;
   }

   .ck.ck-toolbar {
   background: white;
   padding: 0px;
   border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
   }

   .ck.ck-toolbar {
   border-radius: 0;
   }

   .ck.ck-toolbar {
   user-select: none;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
   align-items: center;
   }

   .ck.ck-button,
   a.ck.ck-button {
   min-width: 2em !important;
   min-height: 2em !important;
   }